# Headless Drupal 8.3 - Allow a user to choose their own password via the user registration endpoint, while also sending an email activation link?

Tags: users, emails

The planned user registration process is as follows:

The user enters their email address and chooses their password using the registration form. After registering, an email containing an account activation link is sent to them.

We're using React Native on the front-end.

I'm not sure about the best way to achieve this. Is there an existing module(s) for this?